# Rails Foundation datetime field is formatted oddly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, datetime, zurb-foundation

So I am using Foundation with Rails and I have a datetime field in a form.

```
<div class="field">

  <%= f.datetime_select :played, label: "Around what time will this Song be played?", prompt: true %>

</div>
```

However, rendered, each component (year, month, minute, etc.) appears on a separate full-width line. I cannot figure out how to make all the fields appear in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default `datetime_select` form helper behaviour. If you want a simple text box try using `f.text_field`.

Comment: This seems to work... But It doesn't include the time. And I don't like the format. Do you think there is anyway to do this with the dropdown menus?